# How can display group price greater than regular price in magento?

Tags: php, magento1.9.2.3

I have list of products in which some products have group price is greater than regular price.currently I am getting only minimum price. Please help?

Answer (score 0):

The way Magento works, the lowest available price is *nearly always* shown to a customer. Unless you manually set the price on a product, Magento will automatically calculate what price to show, and the price calculated will be the lowest possible option. The system doesn't care whether the group price is higher, or if the discount is $3 higher than one other option - **the lowest price is always shown.**

Comment: How can I set ?

Comment: The best option is just to make the customer group price lower than the regular price, if you can. You can set it with the Varien_Object->setData() method, setting the key to 'price' and the value to the desired price. You'll likely have to listen to the `catalog_product_load_after` event to do this. You can also listen to the 'catalog_product_get_final_price' event, and specify the custom price with that.